# Imaginary part of vacuum polarization tensor

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I deal with vacuum polarization diagram calculation with help of QED by Landau et al. and I would like to understand one interesting statement. I know how to compute $\Pi_{\mu\nu}(k)$ via dimensional regularization. The tensor can be written as:
$$\Pi_{\mu\nu}(k)\propto\int_p \frac{N_{\mu\nu}(p,k)}{(p^2-m^2+io)((p+k)^2-m^2+io)},$$
but authors stated that imaganiry part of $\Pi_{\mu\nu}(k)$ can be calculated without regularization. In book I don't see why it is true. Therefore, my question is: how I can see that $\mathrm{Im}\,\Pi_{\mu\nu}$ can be calculated without regularization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

First use the a suitable partial fraction decomposition like $\frac{1}{B-A}(\frac{1}{A}-\frac{1}{B})=\frac{1}{AB}$ for any factors $A,B$.

Then use the relation

$\frac{1}{x+io} = P\frac{1}{x}-i\pi \delta(x)$

where $P$ denotes the Cauchy principal value and $x$ can be any Expression. At the end, since the imaginary parts are delta functions, you will have a simple integral over Delta functions.

Comment: I understand how to calculate imaginary part but I dunno why there is no regularization for this part...

Comment: When you obtain Delta functions by using the Principal value relation, you don't Need to regularize the integral